# Handle exception without using try catch in Zend Framework 1

Tags: exception, zend-framework

I have a project which is developed in Zend Framework 1. The project is completed.

Now while I am testing the whole site, some pages thrown exceptions. One of such is below:

> exception 'Zend_Paginator_Exception' with message 'No adapter for type NULL'

I have searched in net and got the steps to add try-catch to this. But it will take much time to check all code and repeat this step.

Can I write a common exception handler which catches all exceptions and handle it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zend framework automatically handles exceptions using the errorController. You can enable it by adding the following line in you config file.

```
resources.frontController.throwExceptions = 0
```

If you want to handle exceptions manually then, rather then writing try/catch block all over the code you can centralize it using the code below.

**Tell Zend Framework to not handle exceptions. Do this in your application.ini**

```
resources.frontController.throwExceptions = 1
```

**Define a custom method to handle exceptions in your Bootstrap class.**

```
public function __handleExceptions(Exception $e){
        //render a view with a simple error message for the user
        //and send an email with the error to admin
    }
```

Override the `_bootstrap()` and `run()` methods of Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap in your Bootstrap class as shown below. This will catch all the exceptions thrown during the bootstrapping and request dispatching process and call your custom exception handler.

```
protected function _bootstrap($resource = null)
    {
        try {
            parent::_bootstrap($resource);
        } catch(Exception $e) {
            $this->__handleExecptions($e);
        }
    }

    public function run()
    {
        try {
            parent::run();
        } catch(Exception $e) {
            $this->__handleExecptions($e);
        }
    }
```

This will eliminate the need of writing try/catch block at multiple places. Hope this helps.

Comment: @Web_Developer What are you implying?

Comment: @Web_Developer You need to override the Bootstrap() and run() methods. In your Bootstrap class. See the details in my answer.

Comment: @Web_Developer Use the Zend_View component and render the message you get by calling $e->getMessage();

Comment: Spelling mistake when you call the function __handleExecptions  Now I could reach there in the function during exception.

Comment: resources.frontController.throwExceptions = 0  It is not working.Please remove this step and modify your comment including the spelling correction..

Answer (score 0):

If you have this line in your index.php

```
$application->bootstrap()->run();
```

You can wrap it with `try` `catch` block

```
try {
    $application->bootstrap()->run();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    //handle all exceptions here
}
```

Of course you can also have many catch blocks for different types of exceptions.

Comment: I have these lines and added the following:

try {
    $application->bootstrap();
    $application->run();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    //handle all exceptions here
    echo "Some error"; exit;
}

But still it shows Exceptions on Screen.